# JPA with Java SE: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

Executing a Java SE JPA standalone application throws the exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test
```

I have found several similar posts but I think that none of them applies to my case with EclipseLink, Java SE and no packaging into deployable files and hence no WEB-INF etc.

The /src/META-INF/persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>SomeEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/somedbname"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="foo"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="bar"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The following jars are on the build path:

- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.4.jar
- eclipselink-2.6.4.jar
- javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar
- postgresql-9.4.1212.jar

Answer (score 1):

I had to provide the persistence namespace in persistence.xml with the xmlns attribute

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but in my case this was the solution. In my Tomcat projects I use a tag: `<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">`, but in this standalone app I had to change `xmlns` and `version` to what @JCvanDamme says...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the eclipselink jar to your ClassPath to check is it's already there or no:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```